# VB.Net Cookie Login

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have an issue with my program.

Ive done a login in vb.net (Visual Studio) which works like a charm. 
However, i need to store the username of the person that has logged in, in some form of cookie.

How can i store the persons username in some form of global "cookie"?

It will be cleared when they log out or the program closes

PS. I dont literally mean a web cookie - just not sure what else to call it. Just a global variable which will store the current user.

---

Related issue - didnt want to create another post...

"Another thing - how do i clear the data that has been set in the "AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData(user, yourvalue)" - when a user logs out it needs to be cleared. how do i do this?"

Comment: If you just want to store the username and this is cleared when they logout or the program closes then just store this in a public variable as you mentioned - the idea behind a cookie is that the information is persistent, what you describe is not the functionality of a cookie

Answer (score 1):

Use FormsAuthentication for your login and once the login is successful set cookie via

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false)
```

Now you can access the username of the logged in user via

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

[Edit]
In the exe...

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData(user, yourvalue)

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData(user)
```

Comment: is this just for a web based program? Mines going to be an EXE - Win Forms

Comment: when you said 'cookie' it usually means web

Comment: yeah, sorry, i didnt know what else to call it - i hoped the "cookie" with the speech marks would highlight the fact i wasnt strictly meaning cookie aha - Will ammend my OP now - Cheers anyway

Comment: Ahh i see - thankyou. What kind of values go into the "yourvalue" bit?

Comment: It is of type object.  literally anything.

Comment: Another thing - how do i clear the data that has been set in the "AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData(user, yourvalue)" - when a user logs out it needs to be cleared. how do i do this?

Comment: look at the signature of that method, it will take two params. One is the variable and the other is the value.  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData(user, null)